# Поисковая система

Tags: алгоритм

Какой алгоритм использовать при написании поисковой системы?

Answer (score 5):

Что должна искать поисковая система? Если текст, то Вам нужно построить так называемый обратный индекс, который, грубо говоря, каждому слову ставит в соответствие набор документов, где это слово встретилось. Для индекса часто используют [B-деревья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) и их модификации, так как они приспособлены к тому, чтобы хранить данные индекса на дисках.

Но обратный индекс уже [есть в PostgreSQL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIN), и в [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Если требуется искать что-то очень многомерное (например, картинки или супер интеллектуально искать тот же текст), то у Вас ничего не получится (шутка), но можно посмотреть [K-d деревья](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) или [учиться](http://simsearch.yury.name/tutorial.html), [учиться](http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/), и ещё раз [учиться](http://shad.yandex.ru/) :), и ещё что-нибудь. Ну попробовать [готовенькое из OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/clustering_and_search_in_multi-dimensional_spaces.html) (но это не масштабируемое решение)